# Increase length of y axis in python matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

I have obtained this image via matplotlib library.

Now I just want to increase y axis length to get a clearer view.

Code is given below:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot_date(df['Condition'],df['Date'], tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False)
plt.title('Scatter plot')
plt.xlabel('Condition')
plt.ylabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the figure size. This can be controlled with feeding a tuple to the `figsize` keyword argument provided to `plt.figure`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 6)) # Figure size in inches (size_x, size_y)
plt.subplot(211)
# plt.plot_date(df['Condition'],df['Date'], tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False)
plt.title('Scatter plot')
plt.xlabel('Condition')
plt.ylabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

The above lines create the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question.

axes = plt.gca()

axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])

axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])

Comment: Date on y axis is dynamic. How can I find min and max date from that?

Comment: This might be helpful. If you are trying to limit the x-axis so that it ranges from a static minimum to a dynamic maximum, with the max being the largest datetime object in your dataset, try

# ...
plt.xlim(
    xmin=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, hour=13), # the one that doesn't change
    xmax=max(x) # the latest datetime in your dataset
)

Comment: -1: OP's image and question show clearly they want the plotting area to be bigger, not a change in visualization bounds (which this achieves).